# Select() System call hangs (does not pick up signal handler when disconnecting network cable)

Tags: sockets, embedded-linux, system-calls

I have the following problem that can't get my head around.
I have the following method (used in an embedded platform) that uses select():

```
int wait_fd_readable(int fd, long msec)
{
    fd_set rset;
    FD_ZERO(&rset);
    FD_SET(fd, &rset);
    struct timeval tv = { msec / 1000, (msec % 1000) * 1000 };
    struct timeval *timeout = msec < 0 ? 0 : &tv;
    return select(fd + 1, &rset, 0, 0, timeout);
}
```

It works very well in general, except when I disconnect the network cable where select seems to hang and never return -1 as expected.
Does anyone have any tip on why might that be?

Comment: Is there some reason you expect select() to return an error when the network cable is disconnected?  In my experience select() will not return due to a cable-disconnect unless you have also taken additional steps (e.g. selecting on a socket of type AF_NETLINK/SOCK_RAW/NETLINK_ROUTE) to detect that change.

Comment: What is the value that gets passed in msec when the network cable is disconnected.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner according to the Select() manual: 
The timeout argument specifies the interval that select() should block waiting for a file descriptor to become ready. The call will block until either: 1) a file descriptor becomes ready; 2) the call is interrupted by a signal handler; or 3) the timeout expires. So I was expecting the second case to take place here

Comment: @KarthikBalaguru, it can vary. In most of the cases the value in msec is 0.

Comment: @Cooli what signal were you expecting to be raised?  (side note:  in a multithreaded program it's indeterminate which thread will receive the signal, which makes signals and multithreading tend to not work very well together)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be in `struct timeval *timeout = msec < 0 ? 0 : &tv;` line:

If `msec` is negative, `timeout` is set to `NULL`, and your `select` call will wait infinitly.

From [man select](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html):

> If timeout is NULL (no timeout), select() can block indefinitely.

Try to replace with:

```
int wait_fd_readable(int fd, long msec)
{
    fd_set rset;
    FD_ZERO(&rset);
    FD_SET(fd, &rset);
    if (msec < 0) {msec = 0;}
    struct timeval tv = { msec / 1000, (msec % 1000) * 1000 };
    return select(fd + 1, &rset, 0, 0, &tv);
}
```

Comment: On timeout, select() returns 0, not -1; that leads me to think that the timeout is the not mechanism the questioner was expecting to depend on for the desired behavior.

Comment: Yes, but well according to  the man select:

       The timeout argument specifies the interval that select() should
       block waiting for a file descriptor to become ready.  The call will
       block until either:
1)  a file descriptor becomes ready;
2)  the call is interrupted by a signal handler; or
3)  the timeout expires.

So I was expecting the second case to take place here...

Comment: @Cooli What kind of connection do you use? UDP, TCP?

Comment: @purplepsycho it is TCP.